# Apache pinot Connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, apache-pinot, pinot

I'm new at working with Apache pinot and I would like you to help me with understanding how it works.
Currently we work with AWS and in an AWS EKS Cluster, Apache Pinot was installed.
I have the link/connection directly and I can use some few commands provides by swagger in the Pinot Controller Api.
The controller service is exposed.

I want to work with pinotdb library in Python, as the [documentation](https://docs.pinot.apache.org/users/clients/python)  says, but when I try a little code like:

```py
from pinotdb import connect


hosted='MyLinkConnection'
#Port=9000
Port=8098


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    conn = connect(host=hosted, port=Port, scheme='http')
    curs = conn.cursor()
    
    #curs.execute("select * from TestTable;")
    curs.execute("select * from TestTable_OFFLINE;")
    
    for row in curs:
        print(row)
    print('Gone')
```

This error is returned:

```json
{
  "errorMessage": "timed out",
  "errorType": "ConnectTimeout",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 15, in lambda_handler\n    curs.execute(\"select * from TestTable_OFFLINE;\")\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pinotdb/db.py\", line 57, in g\n    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pinotdb/db.py\", line 490, in execute\n    **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/httpx/_client.py\", line 1149, in post\n    extensions=extensions,\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/httpx/_client.py\", line 821, in request\n    return self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/httpx/_client.py\", line 912, in send\n    history=[],\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/httpx/_client.py\", line 939, in _send_handling_auth\n    history=history,\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/httpx/_client.py\", line 973, in _send_handling_redirects\n    response = self._send_single_request(request)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/httpx/_client.py\", line 1009, in _send_single_request\n    response = transport.handle_request(request)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/httpx/_transports/default.py\", line 218, in handle_request\n    resp = self._pool.handle_request(req)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py\", line 130, in __exit__\n    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/httpx/_transports/default.py\", line 77, in map_httpcore_exceptions\n    raise mapped_exc(message) from exc\n"
  ]
}
```

I can connect to the console if I enter to *MyLinkConnection*
[image]

But I want to create a connection with pinotdb library or JDBC, always in python, can someone help me?

I already try to expose the services: controller (for console), broker, server and zookeper with their own Ports as the documentation returns.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check:

1. Pinot broker service is exposed to port 8098, e.g. check health of the service should gives you `ok`

```bash
curl http://MyLinkConnection:8098/health
```

2. Seems like you missed the `path` field in the connection?

```py
conn = connect(host=hosted, port=Port, path='/query/sql', scheme='http')')
```